# AES encryption in C# and nodejs

Tags: c#, node.js, encryption, aes

I have a C# encryption which is looking like that:

```
public static string EncryptAes(string value, string password, string iv)
{
    var result = Encrypt<AesManaged>(value, password, iv);
    return result;
}

    static string Encrypt<T>(string value, string password, string salt)
         where T : SymmetricAlgorithm, new()
    {
        DeriveBytes rgb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(salt));

        SymmetricAlgorithm algorithm = new T();

        byte[] rgbKey = rgb.GetBytes(algorithm.KeySize >> 3);
        byte[] rgbIV = rgb.GetBytes(algorithm.BlockSize >> 3);

        ICryptoTransform transform = algorithm.CreateEncryptor(rgbKey, rgbIV);

        using (MemoryStream buffer = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (CryptoStream stream = new CryptoStream(buffer, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.Unicode))
                {
                    writer.Write(value);
                }
            }

            return Convert.ToBase64String(buffer.ToArray());
        }
    }
```

The call to this function returns a string. Now I want to produce the same string in nodejs. I'm trying with npm crypto in the following manner:

```
function encrypt(text, password, iv) {
    let cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', password, iv);
    var crypted = cipher.update(text,'utf8','base64')
    crypted += cipher.final('base64');
    return crypted;
}
```

The problem is that I can't produce the same strings.

The sole purpose of this is that I need to decrypt the c# encrypted data as shown above in nodejs. I can't change the encryption, but I can require any npm in node.

Comment: How can anyone guess what that `Encrypt<AesManaged>` does? Encryption doesn't produce text. That's your method, only you know what goes on in there.

Comment: Don't force people to guest what `crypto` is either. I'd assume it's a third party library. Which one? What did you use for input, what did you get as output?

Comment: ops, sry, part of the code was not copied

Comment: Your C# code uses UTF16 encoding to get the bytes while tour Javascript code uses UTF8. This assumes that `cipher.update(text,'utf8','base64')` means `get the bytes from that string using UTF8 encoding and return the result as base64`